# Select multiple column from 2 different tables and count the selected column

Tags: mysql

can you teach and help me about my mysql code. The question are as follows.

Query A

```
SELECT gbp_sender_date,COUNT(*) AS total_post
FROM guestbook_post
GROUP BY gbp_sender_date DESC;
```

Query B

```
SELECT v_date, COUNT(*) AS total_view
FROM visitor_detail_2 
GROUP BY v_date DESC;
```

Query C

```
SELECT v.v_date, g.gbp_sender_date
FROM visitor_detail_2 v
LEFT JOIN guestbook_post g ON v.v_date = g.gbp_sender_date
GROUP BY v.v_date DESC;
```

Output Query A

```
----------------------------
gbp_sender_date| total post |

----------------------------
2019-04-09     |    5

2019-04-08     |    22   

2019-04-05     |     5

2019-04-04     |     5

2019-04-03     |     5

2019-04-02     |     5

2019-04-01     |     5

-----------------------------
```

Output Query B

```
----------------------------
v_date         | total view

----------------------------
2019-04-09     |     9

2019-04-08     |     8

2019-04-05     |     5

2019-04-04     |     4

2019-04-03     |     3

2019-04-02     |     2

2019-04-01     |     1

-----------------------------
```

The question is how can I alter my code in Query C so that i can get expected output like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------
gbp_sender_date| total post |   v_date       | total view

---------------------------------------------------------
2019-04-09     |     5      | 2019-04-09     |     9      

2019-04-08     |    22      | 2019-04-08     |     8      

2019-04-05     |     5      | 2019-04-05     |     5      

2019-04-04     |     5      | 2019-04-04     |     4      

2019-04-03     |     5      | 2019-04-03     |     3      

2019-04-02     |     5      | 2019-04-02     |     2      

2019-04-01     |     5      | 2019-04-01     |     1      

----------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the results you want from Query C would be to `JOIN` Query A and Query B together:

```
SELECT g.*, v.*
FROM (SELECT gbp_sender_date,COUNT(*) AS total_post
      FROM guestbook_post
      GROUP BY gbp_sender_date) g
JOIN (SELECT v_date, COUNT(*) AS total_view
      FROM visitor_detail_2 
      GROUP BY v_date) v ON v.v_date = g.gbp_sender_date
ORDER BY g.gbp_sender_date DESC
```